# PHP read typescript file and extract type

Tags: typescript, php-7.4

I googled for a while but I can't seem to find a generic way to read a typescript file via PHP and retrieve the type information about a defined typescript variable within that typescript file.
My approach would be to parse the typescript file, extract the typescript variable and try to recursively get all information about that type. But that seems like a lot of effort for such a simple thing.

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. Why do you even need to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can try `tsserver`: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Standalone-Server-%28tsserver%29

Comment: tsserver seems to be a good candidate!